# Get image width and height as computed by browser from a base64 ajax loaded image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the **width and the height of base64 encoded image loaded via ajax** as **computed by the browser**, **not the real/original size**, but the size the browser has computed to display the image (the so called `clientWidth`). I understand that the image must be loaded before getting its sizes, but I keep getting `zero` or `undefined`.

This is the nearest working code I manage to work out:

```
var image_sizes = {};
$('.picture').one('load', function() {
    image_sizes.width = this.width;
    image_sizes.height = this.height;
    console.log(image_sizes.width);
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

but it returns the real/original width and height. If I change `this.width` with `this.clientWidth`, it returns `zero`.

The other codes I tryied do not even work as the image is base64 and it's loaded via ajax.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to [Bobby Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5058/bobby-jack) tip in comments below the following:

```
$('.picture')[0].width
```

works fine provided that width and height are checked **after the image is fully loaded**.

Comment: Normally the browser displays an image in its native size. If you want the size after being affected by CSS, place it somewhere the CSS has an effect.

Comment: Image is loaded and resized to fit inside a 500x450 div. But as the image  keeps its aspect ratio it may be height 500px and width 320px for example, so I do not know what are the computed width and height of the image.

Comment: Is there a specific browser you are trying to get this to work in? What happens when you enter $('.picture')[0].width in the console? That works for me on a browser-resized image. Did you mean "on" instead of "one" in the second line?

Comment: No, not a specific browser. I need the computed width and height to calculate the difference with the real widht and height so to be able to crop the image by editing the preview (which is smaller) but then crop the real image (If you crop a thumbnail and then try to crop the real image using the same x1, y1, x2, y2 coords the area will not match on the bigger image). Yes I meant `on`(but it works with `one` too!) Don't know where to enter `$('.picture')[0]` in Firefox console.